# Need Guide line for Jquery and Update panel for using in asp.net webform project

Tags: jquery, asp.net

first time i am going to develop a e-commerce based website with jquery and update panel together. i have some questions.

1) i hard that update panel and script manager emit huge javascript related line in the page. is it true. if yes the what approach i need to follow as a result my page would be more optimize and very fast to download in client machine.

2) is there any update panel and script manager available which emit all jquery related script in the page. so briefly i want to know is there any update panel and script manager available which is jquery based.

3) many javascript and webpage minifier is available. so i just need to which one is the best for maximum minification of page data,css and javascript. even also which can be work with codebehind and easy to incorporation.

4) i need to know how to work with update panel as a result true partial postback will occur. i hard update panel causes full postback which i dont want for any small changes after post back. i need truly partial postback update panel.

5) how to easily history maintain when i will work with update panel? guide me what i need to do for maintaining history when using update panel partial postback.

6) history maintain when i will work with pagemethod. suppose i call a serverside function with pagemethod and populate my page element and after that if user click on back button then previous state should be displayed. how to do it with pagemethod and icallback technology.

7) how to develop a deffered loading of data.

8) how to develop database driven url re-write.

9) i need a small free cms for inserting html data & image to our db table and later we will show those data in our page. which small cms i should go through.

10) what would be the best choice for making our static hyperlink url to search engine friendly url. as a example http://mysite.com?catid=01&prodid=0021. i want to write a common routine which will re-write my all hyperlink source url with some convention like http://mysite.com/01/0021. so guide me how to develop that type of routine. here i am not talking about page url re-write rather i want to change the hyperlink src with routine which will generate a search engine friendly url.

please guide me....i already asked many question here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't use WinForms or updatePanel they pollute the page with junk. If you want lightweight try ASP.NET MVC. Alternatively just send html and javascript over the wire. Make sure to hand optimise it. Make sure to use ajax / comet / websockets manually.

2) UpdatePanel, jQuery and ScriptManager aren't very related. Just use ScriptManager to include jQuery. UpdatePanel is an ASP.NET control that generates HTML/JS and has nothing to do with jQuery

3) Ask a seperate question or use google.

4) Update panels do partial postbacks using ajax.

5) Please rephrase more coherently.

6) Use HTML5 history API (not supported in IE :() Or use the viewstate (which is bloated and slow).

7) Too vague.

8) Too vague.

9) [ASP.NET CMS](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+cms&safe=active)

10) Use ASP.NET MVC. It does this kind of routing good-ness. Or use [ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Comment: i don't know MVC and it need good time to have command over it...so i have to go for web form bcoz i know it.

Comment: @user728750 I added the ASP.NET routing link. And also mentioned you dont need ASP.NET MVC, you can just send html and js manually.